# Reminder module recommendation

Tags: 7

I am after a "reminder" module, which will enable the site users to subscribe to nodes/content types in order to receive reminders of closing dates and notifications of when the node has been updated/changed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout this module [Subscriptions](http://drupal.org/project/subscriptions)

> This module enables users to subscribe to be notified of changes to
>   nodes or taxonomies, such as new comments in specific forums, or
>   additions to some category of blog. Once enabled, all nodes will have
>   an additional link that allows the user to change their subscriptions.
>   Users have tab on their user screen to manage their own subscriptions.
>   Users can also set an auto-subscribe function which notifies the user
>   if anyone comments on posts they have made. Admins can turn this on by
>   default.

Comment: Thank you @Anoop Joseph
This is the module I am currently using. How does it compare to Notifications?

Answer (score 1):

There is also [Notifications](http://drupal.org/project/notifications) module

> This is a complete Subscriptions/Notifications Framework aiming at
>   extendability and scalability. It allows any number of plug-ins
>   defining new event types or subscription types or a different user
>   interface.

Read [Notifications Framework](http://drupal.org/node/252592)

Comment: Thank you @Nikhil M
I will check it out. Am currently using Subscriptions. How do they compare, do you know?